# Firebase CocoaPods Installation Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cocoapods

I'm trying to install Firebase via CocoaPods for my Objective-C iOS Application. My Podfile is as follows:

```
target 'RandomName' do

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'

end
```

When I run `pod install`, I get the following error:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Firebase/Core` required by `Podfile`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Core`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

The latest version of CocoaPods is installed, and I have tried running pod repo update. Having a Podfile of the following works fine, but when I try to `@import Firebase;` in my `AppDelegate.m` file, Xcode cannot find the module.

```
target 'RandomName' do

pod 'Firebase'

end
```

However, the following combination does not install:

```
target 'RandomName' do

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'

end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: While using pod 'Firebase' in podfile & after importing Firebase as @import Firebase; do you build the project? If no then try building it. Because Xcode complains about not finding the module but upon building the error goes away. When I was integrating some other framework I faced similar issue & spent hours on it. But after building it started working. So maybe same case might be with you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check what version of Firebase is installed when you use pod 'Firebase'. For me it installs 2.4.3 which is an old version. The docs say that the pod should install 3.2 using that pod. It explains why the other pods don't work as they are part of Firebase 3. Pod update doesn't update Firebase to the latest version either. Even forcing a version doesn't work. It can't seem to find the new Firebase versions even though they are in the same podspec.

Here is how I solved it:

- make sure you have the latest version of git installed
- make sure you have cocoapods >= 1.0.0 installed
- delete your pods repo (run `pod repo remove master`) and use `pod setup` to make a new one
- use the following in your pod file

  `pod 'Firebase/Auth'`

  `pod 'Firebase/Database'`

  `pod 'Firebase/Core'`

(use whatever you want, just don't use 'Firebase')

- `pod install`
- everything should install properly

Comment: Ahh finally! Running 'pod repo remove master' to remove the Pods repo and then running 'pod setup' and finally 'pod install' did the trick!!! I did not need to downgrade to 1.0.0 however. Thanks for your help!

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!  THANK YOU!!!!  THANK YOU!!!! 
This worked!

 'pod repo remove master' to remove the Pods repo and then running 'pod setup' and finally 'pod install' did the trick!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. `pod repo remove master` and then `pod setup` did the trick.

Answer (score 13):

Running 'pod repo remove master' to remove the Pods repo //removes the library

Running 'pod setup'    //clones the updated git repo for specs which takes long time as its size is beyond 300K (Be patient!)

Running 'pod install'   //problem is solved

Comment: Even though it took a lot of time for pod setup this solved the issue for me. Thanks.

Comment: 'pod repo remove master' to remove the Pods repo and then running 'pod setup' and finally 'pod install' did the trick!!!

Comment: Excellent - took about 15 minutes for me and immediately solved my 
- `Firebase/Core` required by `Podfile`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Core`.
error even though I had up to date git and pod versions.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to add

frameworks
  use_frameworks!

after target 'RandomName' line

and adding

platform :ios, '9.0'

before target ....

Comment: I have the following Podfile according to your changes, but it did not work: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'RandomName' do
use_frameworks!

    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
end

Answer (score 1):

A couple of items to try.  From your question, you did try the first two items, but leaving here for completeness of my answer.

- The error response you get is helpful.  Follow the steps for `pod repo update`
- Make sure your `pod` is up to date.

  ```
  pwd> pod --version
  1.0.0
  ```
- Make certain that your git is up to date.  I had a build machine that had an outdated git (1.7), and I had the same exact error
  -

When I updated to this version from git 1.7 it worked fine.

```
pwd> git --version
git version 2.8.1
```

- My Podfile for using Firebase Dynamic Links
- run `pod init` from the folder where your .xcodeproj is
- Be sure to only launch the .xcworkspace instead of the .xcodeproj from here out.

```html
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'the-name-of-target' do
 pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
end
```

Comment: I updated Git to version 2.8.2 and already had Cocoapods version 1.0.0, but still no luck. Running pod repo update was also not successful.

Comment: Updated answer with my Podfile.  The call to `use_frameworks!` is outside of the target/end structure

Comment: That's strange - still cocoapods will install just Firebase fine, but the second I try and add something after it like in your Podfile it does not work. The Podfile you provided (after I replaced the target name) still does not install correctly.

Comment: Sorry to hear the all the issues.  I struggled as well.  I added two other items in my edited answer (`pod init` & .xcworkspace).

Comment: Still nothing, sorry. I'm not using Swift, so should I leave use_frameworks! commented?

Comment: I would leave use_frameworks!  commented    This is what a fresh Podfile for Objective C looks like 
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'firebase-demo' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for firebase-demo

end

Answer (score 1):

The Same problem occurred while on **pod install** command.

Please relaunch terminal and navigate to your Xcode project then

simply fire same **pod install** command. 'Firebase/Database' will installed successfully :)

Answer (score 0):

I just doing following step to fix this error:

```
$pod setup -- verbose
```

Then do `$pod install`

that works for me and my pod file is:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'the-name-of-target' do
 pod 'Eureka', '~> 1.6'
end
```

**UPDATE:**

Then you can remove your master and re-install cocoapods using following code:

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
rm -rf master
pod setup
```

Comment: Still no luck. Running pod setup --verbose gives me the following warning: 'CocoaPods was not able to update the `master` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose'. Running pod repo update --verbose gives me the same warning again.

Comment: And when I try to install I get the same error I've been having

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and my solution was to downgrade `Cocoapods` to `1.0.0`, because `Cocoapods` `1.0.1` didn't work as I expected. Everything works great now!

- `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -v 1.0.1`
- `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.0.0`

My `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'XXX' do

  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

For people still having problems with this. When directly coping the firebase walkthourgh website, the install string is:

```
pod `Firebase/Core`
```

While it should have been:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

No need for pod setup if this applies to you too.

Answer (score 0):

Update **Git** and **Cocoapods** to the last version:

Git: `$ brew update && brew upgrade`

Cocoapods: `$ pod repo update`