# Framework not found Firebase Analytics

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

Hi I just opened my xCode project after 1 or 2 months, and an error automatically appeared :

```
ld: framework not found FirebaseAnalytics
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I did some searches and I see that FireBase is a new "tool" implemented by Google, but I didn't say to my project to use it, I don't know how FireBase appeared in my project, because of I'm using Google Analytics ?

- So I wan't to know if I have to use FireBase to use Google Analytics, if yes, how can I resolve this error and add perfectly FireBase ?
- Or can I just delete it and use only Google Analytics ? So how to delete it ?

Already see this: [framework not found FirebaseAnalytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717889/framework-not-found-firebaseanalytics) Doesn't helped me.

I have errors wive command lines:

```
[!] Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitised. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.

[!] The `SolutisTests [Debug]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-SolutisTests/Pods-SolutisTests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `SolutisTests [Release]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-SolutisTests/Pods-SolutisTests.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Comment: How are you adding the framework to your project? With Pods? Carthage? Manual import?

Comment: Sorry I missed the information, I use cocoa pods @DejanSkledar

Comment: Make sure you updated your pods in your project and also CocoaPods with `gem install`.

Comment: @DejanSkledar Pod install no ? or update, I didn't used gem commands

Comment: @DejanSkledar Look my edit please I get errors with command lines

Comment: Post your `Podfile`. There's an error there.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 Yes there was an error with quotes, I resolved it now, but I still have this error: target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`

Comment: Well take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26445806/5654848). It might help resolve your issue.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 Always did it ( I looked at many subject, but no way

Comment: Just paste your `podfile`. Let me look at it.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 Sorry there was a mistake, now it's work I may have to put $(inherited) for the Test target, now it's running

Comment: It's alright. Happy to help! :)

Comment: @Dershowitz123 thanks for the help here. Do you feel like you could turn your help into a useful answer that others might benefit from?

Comment: @Ben can you please explain what did you do? I am having the same problem