# Firebase framework not found

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I've been trying to migrate my project to cocoapods.

I feel like i'm almost there but I'm stuck in:

> ld: framework not found Firebase for architecture x86_64
>       error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm trying to compile using my "app.xcworkspace" and the project looks like this:

[image: project navigator]

Also:

[image: libraries]

I've tried starting other projects and firebase works there so it's a problem with THIS project settings... Any idea?

My podfile looks like this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, ‘8.0’

target 'Parti' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Parti

    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'

  target 'PartiTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'PartiUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

It might be relevant to add that the error happens when xcode tries to "Link /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parti-gsdsljzobcnqjkgutfpjasgrsfck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parti.app/Parti"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer. Seems like I had an old geofire version and the new one is not available as a Pod yet...

[Github Issue link](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/48)

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 13):

I know it sounds far fetch, but:

1. Clean the project. Product -> Clean
2. Restart `XCode` (not always needed)
3. Run `pod update` & `pod install`from the project folder

**Update:** The `Podfile` should more like:

```
    use_frameworks!

    target 'Parti' do
      pod 'Firebase'
      pod 'Firebase/Storage'
      pod 'Firebase/Auth'
      pod 'Firebase/Database'
    end

    target 'PartiUITests' do
      pod 'Firebase'
      pod 'Firebase/Storage'
      pod 'Firebase/Auth'
      pod 'Firebase/Database'
    end
```

Comment: Try and this Podfile and repeat step 3

Comment: `pod update && pod install` worked for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have added $(inherited) in your Header Search Paths, Framework Search Paths and Library Search Paths for your project target.

Also make sure that in frameworks folder in your project file(Not in your Pods, click on the Project Name in the Project Navigator), the "libPods-YourProjectName.a" is not red. If yes, delete it and build again.

Answer (score 3):

add $PROJECT_DIR/Pods (make it recursive)

to Framework search paths

for whatever reason only this helped me, maybe you too

Answer (score 0):

Some hints :

- Make sure that your Podfile is correct (did you forget to uncomment the use_frameworks! line ? Have you correctly added the pod ?)
- Have you forgotten to run "pod install" ?
- Have you tried cleaning the project and the build folder ?

Comment: Tried everything you said but cleaning of the build folder. Just did that and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is your project name is not ASCII. For example, you may have Chinese characters in the name.

In such case, In "general" -> "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content", remove "Pods___.framework", and add the one with the right name under "Pods/" would help.

Comment: Already solved by https://stackoverflow.com/a/38359079/5771560