# ld: framework not found FirebaseAnalytics after upgrading from 4.x.x to 5.x.x firebase through cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Xcode starts encountering this error

> ld: framework not found Firebase-XXXXXX

where XXXXXX would be any framework listed in the `podfile`, here is the specific part of that podfile

```
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

after I update the existing project's firebase frameworks (which were in `4.x.x version` at the time of starting this project) to the newer `5.x.x version` of firebase (for using ML-Kit) using `pod install` in the project directory, it fails to compile it.

**Steps taken so far after going through the web,**

The following is done with a backed copy of running 4.x.x version of project,

a) Tried all answers from this green ticked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717889/framework-not-found-firebaseanalytics)

b) Cleared Xcode's Derived data for this project, cocoapods cache uninstalled/ reinstalling it entirely. Commented out firebase part in podfile and then pod install it twice (one for removing the firebase and second for installing it again)

c) Manually copying the error generating firebase dependancies to the project's folder (bad idea, 52 bugs 300+ warnings)

Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So what the main question? It's normal way to update a project when you try to use new framework because of some features can be inactive without this fixes.

Comment: Upon upgrade all of the mentioned frameworks in the podfile, fails to compile. As mentioned at the start of the question: `ld: framework not found Firebase-XXXXXX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Firebase dependancies has various linkages between them, even if your project doesn't need, For instance -- for this dependency: `ld: framework not found FirebaseDatabaseUI` was not required in the project and was taken out by these steps,

Goto

> Target(project_name)-> Build Settings-> search(Other linker flags)-> from
>   their remove the conflicting dependency

Be sure to build back and check if that dependency was even been used or not, in my case it wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the Podfile:

`pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'`

In Firebase 5, FirebaseAnalytics is no longer an implicit dependency of Database, Messaging, and Storage.

The Firebase docs recommend always including `FirebaseAnalytics` to include Analytics.

Comment: This seems to work, but unable to get past this one: `ld: framework not found FirebaseDatabaseUI`

Comment: No luck, on the side note -- had a cocoapods warning: `target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-x/Pods-x.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation`, cleared that and tried as you recommended still the bug persists