# Adding the admob dependency crashes my app

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I'm trying to integrate admob in my flutter app and whenever I add the 
`firebase_admob: ^0.5.2` dependency my app crashes.

`Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           10,3s
Configuring the default Firebase app...
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
Syncing files to device iPhone Xʀ...
Lost connection to device.
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001108526fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fdfeac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110852269 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Runner                              0x0000000106bb9dd2 GADVerifyApplicationID + 148
    4   Runner                              0x0000000106bba967 GADVerifyApplicationID + 3113
    5   libdispatch.dylib           <…>`

I've tried to change the ADMOB_APP_ID in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and in the `Info.plist`, as well as change the version of the dependency to 0.9.0

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall your pods?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38135857/11661407)

Comment: Your crash is over iOS. Did you updated the admob package to the latest version? firebase_admob 0.9.0+1

Comment: having same issue