# Unable to update firebase latest framework from podfile

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

When I try to update my Firebase through cocoapods, Always its updating to 3.17.0 version - which is old. As per firebase docs, 6.4.0 is the latest version for iOS.  Why i am not able to update to latest.

I have tried multiple ways to resolve this. But no luck.

[FireBase Cocoa Pods Installation Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485141/firebase-cocoa-pods-installation-not-working/38135857#38135857)

[FireBase Cocoa Pods Installation Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485141/firebase-cocoa-pods-installation-not-working)

platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'the-name-of-target' do
 pod 'Firebase'
end

I should be able to update to latest firebase framework.

**Edit: Solved with workaround.**

Google Signin framework having the dependency.  As work around removed google sigenin pod & added as framework. Now i am able to update to latest the firebase to latest.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear pods cache and reinstall CocoaPods

Comment: Tried all kinds of cleanup.  Seems like is has some dependency on Google signin pod.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating pods?

command for update all pods

```
pod update
```

for specific pod

```
pod update POD_NAME
```

Comment: Google Signin framework having the dependency.  As work around removed google sigenin pod & added as framework. Now i am able to update to latest the firebase to latest.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the generated `Podfile.lock` to see which dependency forces Firebase's version to 3.x.

Comment: Solved with workaround.

Google Signin framework having the dependency. As work around removed google sigenin pod & added as framework. Now i am able to update to latest the firebase to latest. Thanks.